# How to import _udunits2 on Google Colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to import _udunits2 on Google Colab. I have managed to install it through Conda. However, after successful installation, when I attempt to import the package, it returns this error message:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-f9eb376cf338> in <module>()
----> 1 from cf_units import _udunits2

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cf_units/__init__.py in <module>()
     43 from .util import _OrderedHashable, approx_equal
     44 
---> 45 from cf_units import _udunits2 as _ud
     46 from cf_units._udunits2 import (UT_ASCII, UT_ISO_8859_1, UT_LATIN1, UT_UTF8,
     47                                 UT_NAMES, UT_DEFINITION)

ImportError: cannot import name '_udunits2' from 'cf_units' (/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cf_units/__init__.py)
```

Anyone have any ideas on how to import this package?